# How do I write a secure but simple loginscript using these technologies?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

I need to protect an html page from non-registered users. Only
registered users are granted access to the page.
To this end, I need to write an web application using maven as the project manegment Tool, eclipse as IDE, Hibernate and postgres for the database, XHTML, AJAX for the log-in/register page. Also I need to use Spring Framework as a container and Spring Security for authentication handling. Lastly, the java code has to be written using TDD and JUnit.

Now, I know very Little about all these tools, and combining them all seems overwhelming. But I have to include them in the project. My questions are therefore:

What Maven archetype will be best for this Little project?

How do I link my database and javacode to the XHTML page?

What is a container?

How do I make this serversided?

Is Spring Framework and Spring security the same thing?

Do you have any good sources for learning about the different tools?
I can't seem to find any Spring tutorials and TDD implementation examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make a question on your title. Actual title does not provide any useful information about your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I am so confsed about all this, that I couldn't put Words on what my issues are. But I will try to put a more descriptive title.

Comment: You'll have much better luck if you ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should use this Maven archetype: maven-archetype-webapp

2) You link your database to your Java code with Hibernate. Read more here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/orm_overview.htm Then, you "generate" the XHTML page from your Java code.

3) The Spring framework is a very big thing to learn if you don't know anything about Java web. Try servlets + jsp first. (I know you have to use Spring but without basic knowledge you won't be able to)

4) It IS "server sided" by default, this only shows you are not aware of the technology.

5) No, they are separate modules.

I'm searching for some resources that can help you to start but without knowing how much you know it's hard. I'm going to add links to my answer if I find any.

Read about these:

MVC pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Basic Spring Security: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

Spring + Hibernate: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is really helpful. I know basic java and SQL and the concepts of relational databases. While I know some theoretical stuff, I know very Little about the practical part, which is why I need help. I learned the basics of maven, postgres and hibernate, but not enough.

Comment: I know it can be really-really hard to solve the puzzle, or even to ask anything specific if you don't see the big picture. I'm glad if it helped in any way.